# "does not name a type" error when referencing a typedef from a class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef

I have the following definition of a typedef in a class

```
/*
 *ReportData.h
 */
class ReportData {

public:

    /** Classifiers information  **/
    typedef struct{ 
        char *classifier;
        uint8_t numCategories;
        char **categories;    
        int *ranges;          
    } Classification;
};
```

This code is later referenced as follows

```
/*
 * DynamicCarDetection.cpp 
 */

    #include <DataReport.h>

    int numOfClassGroups = 1;
    int numOfCategories = 2;
    ReportData::Classification *vehiclesClassificators;

    vehiclesClassificators = new ReportData::Classification[numOfClassGroups];

    vehiclesClassificators[i].numCategories = NumOfcategories;
    vehiclesClassificators[i].categories = new char *[numOfcategories];
```

When I try to compile with this command

```
g++ -c DynamicCarDetection.cpp -I ./
```

I get this error on each reference to vehiclesClassificators

> DynamicCarDetection.cpp:12:1: error: ‘vehiclesClassificators’ does not
>   name a type

Looks like an obvious error of name scoping, but I've struggling to understand what the problem is, because apparently, the typedef ReportData::Classification is being recognized.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are all the statements inside some functions in the `DynamicCarDetection.cpp `? Moreover, why are you using gcc when the code is of C++?

Comment: why use `typedef struct` in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, sentences (except some corner cases) must be part of a function body. And in your CPP file there are none, so the compiler gets confused about what you are doing.

```
#include <DataReport.h>

void DoThings()
{
    int numOfClassGroups = 1;
    //....
}
```

Comment: Embarrassingly obvious! noob. Not an excuse, but it cames from making test trying to get static initialization for an array of structs to work, hence why the code ended at the definition section.

Answer (score 0):

even I find the answer is too late.

I'm bad English, and express is not good, thanks. I find one thing will likely cause this problem.

Did you find any old error files in your project? I see an error tips file which name's tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp in my project when I use g++ to compile the project in vscode. But I'm setting some implicit selections in settings.jsion file, which causes the file to disappear. I see the implicit error tips file which causes the problem, by delecte the settings.json file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).